# Struct to bits c++

Tags: c++, struct, bit, bitset

I am learning C++ and I wonder if it is possible to decompose a structure object into a sequence of bits?

```
// The task is this! I have a structure
struct test {
  // It contains an array
    private:
    int arr [8];

    public:
    void init () {
      for (int i = 0; i <8; i ++) {
        arr [i] = 5;
     }

    }
};


int main () {
  // at some point this array is initialized
    test h;
    h.init ();

    // without referring to the arr field and its elements, we must convert the structure to this format
    // we know that int is stored there, and these are 32 bits -> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101. 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101. - and there are 8 such pieces by number
    // elements in the array

  return -1;
}
```

Well, we know the size of the array too. We need to convert the structure object to a sequence of bits:

00000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000000000101

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just create a function to take each element of the array and print its bits. Or you can copy the contents of the structure object `h` inty a byte array and print the bits from that array (but beware of padding!).

Comment: What have you tried? Have you studied the bitwise operators? What problems did you run into when trying to use them?

Comment: the keyword is "serialization" and it's very common for exchanging data between runtime platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard answer for converting number into bit strings is to you `std::bitset`. I will use a more low level approach. And use a bit mask and & operation to mask out single bits and then assign the corresdponding characters to the resulting string.

Masking woks with the bit and operator and on the locical AND operation

```
Bit Mask      AND
0   0         0
0   1         0
1   0         0
1   1         1
```

You see, 0 and 1 is 0. And 1 and 1 is 1.

That allows us to access a bit in a byte.

```
Byte: 10101010
Mask: 00001111
--------------
      00001010
```

And this mecahnism we will use.

But, I cannot imagine that this is homework, because of the dirty `reintepret_cast` that would be needed, by accessing the struct from outside.

Anyway. Let me present this solution to you.

I find it utmost ugly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

// The task is this! I have a structure
struct test {
    // It contains an array
private:
    int arr[8];

public:
    void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            arr[i] = 5;
        }
    }
};

// Convert an int to a string with the bit representaion of the int
std::string intToBits(int value) {

    // Here we will store the result
    std::string result{};

    // We want to mask the bit from MSB to LSB
    unsigned int mask = 1<<31;

    // Now we will work on 4 bytes with 8bits each
    for (unsigned int byteNumber = 0; byteNumber < 4; ++byteNumber) {
        for (unsigned int bitNumber = 0; bitNumber < 8; ++bitNumber) {

            // Mask out bit and store the resulting 1 or 0 in the string
            result += (value & mask) ? '1' : '0';

            // Next mask
            mask >>= 1;
        }
        // Add a space between bytes
        result += ' ';
    }
    // At the end, we do want to have a point
    result.back() = '.';
    return result;
}

int main() {
    // At some point this array is initialized
    test h;
    h.init();

    // Now do dirty, ugly, and none compliant type cast
    int* test = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&h);
 
    // Convert all bytes and show result
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < 8; ++k) 
        std::cout << intToBits(test[k]) << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh! Okay, I will know about reinterpret_cast, I haven't heard of it before. Yes, I agree,  this  transformations  - perversions :)  It was originally thought that there was a way to convert a struct or class object to a raw byte stream. For example char * bytes; And then   check the bit in the byte is raised and display its value.